# When reading CSV files the output is strange

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I have a CSV file which looks like this:

```
1ttAAAttAnaattFrench PolynesiattPFttAustralia and Oceaniatt-17.352606tt-145.509956
2ttAAEttAnnabattAlgeriattDZttAfricatt36.822225tt7.809167
3ttAAFttApalachicolattUnited StatesttUSttNorth Americatt29.7276066tt-85.0274416
4ttAAGtt\NttBrazilttBRttSouth Americatt\Ntt\N
```

I use this gem to fetch data: https://github.com/tilo/smarter_csv

This is the code I use to show data in terminal console:

```
filename = 'db/csv/airports_codes.csv'
options = {
  :col_sep => 'tt',
}
records = SmarterCSV.process(filename, options)

puts records
```

I put these files in seeds.rb file because I will modify this code later to seed my database with data. This last line of code is there so I can see how it looks like. So I run `rake db:seed`

And the output is obviously huge because there are around ~5k lines. Now the first problem is that I can't see all of the data in my terminal. When I scroll to the top this is the first item (note that ID is 4674 which means it displayed last ~250 items):

```
{:"1"=>4674, :aaa=>"YPJ", :anaa=>"Aupaluk", :french_polynesia=>"Canada", :pf=>"CA", :australia_and_oceania=>"North America", :"_17.352606"=>59.2967, :"_145.509956"=>-69.5997}
```

How do I see others items?

The second problem is that key names are really weird. How do I rename them, or even better, how do I use arrays instead of hashes?

Comment: The key names are due to the SmarterCSV treating the first line as the headers row. There's probably an option to override that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the option

```
:headers_in_file => false
```

in options, that should sort the problem out. 
i.e.

```
filename = 'db/csv/airports_codes.csv'
options = {
  :col_sep => 'tt',
  :headers_in_file => false
}
records = SmarterCSV.process(filename, options)
```